# How to define two JRDataSource inside a Java application?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have two bar charts in my report which must be filled by two lists of objects. I don't want to put the query inside my report. I want to pass these two lists from my java application. I have done it with one list of objects and one bar chart, but I don't know how I can do it with two.

Is it possible to define two *JRDataSource* inside a *Java* application? If yes, how I can fill the report?

```
    List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();    
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employee, true);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(input,parameters,datasource);
    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, output);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create e.g. two JRBeanCollectionDatasources and pass them as parameters to your report. Then, use the parameters as datasource expressions for your charts.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. If I pass these two JRBeanCollectionDatasources as parameters, how I can set the third parameter of the fillReport method as a datasource? This is a main part of my problem.

Comment: Thomas, I did exactly whatever you said, but the result is an empty PDF. I defined two parameters (MyList1 and MyList2 - java.util.Collection)and two datasets. Then, I sat Dataset1 for first bar chart and Dataset2 for second bar chart. I selected use datasource expression for both of them with $P{MyList1} for first and $P{MyList2} for second bar chart.